# asp.net mvc - pass text box value to a hidden value with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass the value of a text box to a hidden field. I am currently setting a default value to the field, but the user may change it before the submitting of the form. I thought this could be accomplished with jquery, but I feel I am missing a piece here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        var value = $("#myTextBoxVal").val();
        $('#myHiddenFieldVal').val(value);
    });
});
```

The above provides me with the default value only. But as I mentioned above, I need the value that exists when the form submits, either the default or the user input.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`change`**](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event like following.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myTextBoxVal").change(function() {
        $('#myHiddenFieldVal').val(this.value);
    }).change();
});
```

Comment: is it working for default value? if user does not change the #myTextBoxVal value?